# How can I perform conditional splitting in python?

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I want to split string with comma when comma is not surrounded by ().

```
str = r"a,b,c,test(1,2,3),g,h,test(2,4,6)"
```

Desired split

```
split = ['a','b','c','test(1,2,3)','g','h','test(2,4,6)']
```

how can I do using regex python

My efforts so far,

```
splits = [m.start() for m in re.finditer(',', string_i)]

paranths = {10: 16, 26: 32} #using function

lst = []

first = 1
for l in splits:
    print l
    for m in paranths:
        if (l < m and l < paranths[m]):
            #print m,':',l,':',paranths[m]
            lst.append(string_i[first:l])
            first = l+1
            break
            break
```

Comment: what is your effort so far. post your code here

Comment: Can your sample string contain something like one of these examples? `a,b,c,test(1,2,(3,4,5)),g` or `a,b,c,test)(1,2,3))(,g,h`. If this is the case, you cannot do this properly with regex (recursive behavior and invalid bracket syntax).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As said above you can use negative look behind and ahead pattern matching.

```
import re

my_str = r"a,b,c,test(1,2,3),g,h,test(2,4,6)"

print(re.split('(?<!\(.),(?!.\))', my_str))
```

Comment: thanks it works for the above string but what should I modify to make it work for my_str = r"a,b,c,test('1','2','3'),g,h,test('2','4','6')"

Comment: r"a,b,c,test('1','2','3'),g,h,test('2','4','6')".replace("'", "")

Please note, that single quote ' is between the double quotes " in the first part

Answer (score 3):

You can use a negative lookbehind and a negative lookahead to find all `,` which are not surrounded by a bracket `)(`.

```
(?<![)(]),(?![)(])
```

Here is a live example: https://regex101.com/r/uEyTN8/2

---

**Details**:

- `(?<!  )` if the characters inside the parenthesis match before the next occurence, it will dismiss the match of the next occurrence
- `(?!   )` if the characters inside the parenthesis match after the occurence, it will dismiss the match of this occurrence
- `[)(]` match parenthesis

Comment: I just saw that you want to skip commas when they are in brackets, not when they are preceded or followed immediately by brackets. So, this might not be the correct solution.

Answer (score 2):

not regex but might work:

```
def my_split(s):

    splits0 = s.split(',')
    splits = []

    BEWEEN_PARENTHESIS = False

    # join everything between parenthesis
    for j, elem in enumerate(splits0):
        if not BEWEEN_PARENTHESIS:
            if "(" in elem:
                BEWEEN_PARENTHESIS = True
                start = j
            else:
                splits.append(elem)

        elif BEWEEN_PARENTHESIS and ")" in elem:

            BEWEEN_PARENTHESIS = False
            splits.append(",".join(splits0[start:j+1]))

    return splits

s = "a,b,c,test(1,2,3),g,h,test(2,4,6)"
print(my_split(s))
```

Comment: Thanks @Ivan Luchko your solution works great. But I want to jump to regex if possible.